# How to neatly chain promises in Javascript

Tags: angular, angular-promise, es6-promise

How can I write this function neater, is returning then resolving it in the timeout callback the best way to do this? I'm asking because I'm new to javascript promises.

```
getStuff(): Promise<any> {
    let self = this;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        self.getData()
            .then(function(resp) {
                self.parse(resp);
            })
            .then(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {                                 
                    resolve();
                }, 5000);
            });
    });  
}
```

Comment: Since this is tagged ES6, you can at least remove some clutter by using array functions. `then( resp => this.parse(resp))`. Fewer braces and keywords, no need for `self`.

Comment: Your function is infinite loop....

Comment: Can you explain in words what you are trying to accomplish because the combination of recursion and timeout leave me confused about the purpose of this code and makes it hard to think about the best way to write this.

Comment: ooh just realised the recursion, I named the outer function incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

See the example below...

```
    getStuff(): Promise<any> {
        let self = this;

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            self.getData()
                .then(function(resp) {
                   return self.parse(resp);   //return here
                })
                .then(function(resp2) {
                    setTimeout(function() {                                 
                        resolve(resp2);
                    }, 5000);
                },
                (err) => reject(err));
        });  
    }
```